# Do something after WKWebView has finished loading a specific url page

Tags: javascript, html, swift3, webview, webkit

I'm trying to cal a function after that a `WKWebView` has finished loading. If I use this:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView!, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
  do something...
}
```

It prints every time I load a page.

In my application instead, I tap a button which loads a webPage and I want to scrape data from that page only when it has finished loading to be sure I  scrape the loaded page and not the previous one. What can I do?

I use `Xcode` with `Swift 3`

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you can check `url` property of `webView` to be sure it is that special web page.

[API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415005-url)